# Find variance of a dataset when a new element is added, using mean and variance of old dataset (n-1)

Tags: probability, variance

Assuming we have mean $\bar{x}_{n-1}$ and variance $\sigma^2_{n-1}$ for some dataset $\mathscr{D}_{n-1}$ with $n-1$ samples. What would be the variance $\sigma^2_{n}$ if we add a new element $x_{*}$ to the dataset (assuming you have computed the new sample mean $\bar{x}_{n-1}$)?

---

From a previous exercise, I know that:

$$
\bar{x}_{n}=\bar{x}_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}(x_{*} - \bar{x}_{n-1})
$$

but I'm having trouble plugging this into:

$$
\sigma^2_{n} = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n})^2}{N}
$$

I *think* the following two equations are true:

$$
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\sigma^2_{n-1} & = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(x_{n-1} - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2}{N-1} \\
\\
\sigma^2_{n} & = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}(x_{*} - \bar{x}_{n-1}))^2}{N} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
Apparently the answer is:
$$
\sigma^2_{n} = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n-1}(x_{*}-\bar{x}_{n-1})(x_{*}-\bar{x}_n)
$$

But not sure how to get there. Would somebody mind helping me understand?

Comment: There is confusion in your use of symbols Also your formula for the sample variance is incorrect. It should be  $\sigma^2_n = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j - \bar{x}_{n})^2}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience I will let $x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ denote the elements $\mathscr{D}_{n-1}$, and let $x_n$ denote the new element $x_*$.

We have
\begin{align}
\sigma_n^2
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x}_{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1}))^2
\\
&=
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left[
(x_i - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2 - \frac{2}{n}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})(x_i - \bar{x}_{n-1}) + \frac{1}{n^2}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2
\right]
& \text{expand the square}
\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x}_{n-1})^2 - \frac{2}{n^2}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1}) \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x}_{n-1})
 + \frac{1}{n^2} (x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2.
\end{align}
Using the fact that $\sigma_{n-1}^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_i - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_i - \bar{x}_{n-1}) = 0$ (note that the sums here are $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}$ not $\sum_{i=1}^n$), we can simplify the above as
\begin{align}
\sigma_n^2
&= \frac{n-1}{n} \sigma_{n-1}^2 + \frac{1}{n}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2
- \frac{2}{n^2}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2
+ \frac{1}{n^2} (x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2
\\
&= \frac{n-1}{n} \sigma_{n-1}^2 + \frac{n-1}{n^2}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2.
\end{align}

To rewrite the second term as $\frac{1}{n-1}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})(x_n - \bar{x}_n)$, note that
\begin{align}
(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})(x_n - \bar{x}_n)
&= (x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1}))
\\
&=(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2 - \frac{2}{n}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}(x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2
\\
&= \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2} (x_n - \bar{x}_{n-1})^2.
\end{align}